# Nicest operators on a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Axler writes in his book that *"nicest operators on $V$ are those for which there is an orthonormal basis of $V$ w.r.t which the operator has a diagonal matrix".* i.e. orthonormal basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors.

It is because, its easy to deal with operators/matrices which are diagonal. But why is the orthonomality of a basis which makes the associated matrix diagonal is required. How does orthonomality of basis makes things easy for us? Why not just any basis w.r.t which matrix is diagonal works as nice as orthonomal basis or a normal basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors. If all we want is to play with the corresponding matrices, diagonalizability should be enough.

---

I am looking for some reasoning that is applied outside Functional analysis.
One thing I can find is that having an orthonomal basis , say $(a_1,a_2,\dots a_n)$ then we can find the coefficients when we express some vector $v$ in terms of $a_i's$, i.e. $v=\sum_1^n\langle v,a_i\rangle a_i$

Comment: Certainly $L=V^TDV$ is much easier to work with than $L=V^{-1}DV$ in practice, and especially when you only care about/can afford to compute the most important columns of $V$.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $T$ is an operator on a finite-dimensional inner product space $V$. Having a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$ is nice, but having an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $T$ is even nicer. As an example of why the orthonormal basis is nicer, consider the question of finding the matrix of $T^*$. With respect to an orthonormal basis, the matrix of $T^*$ is the conjugate transpose of the matrix of $T$. But if the basis is not orthonormal, then finding the matrix of $T^*$ is not so simple. Stated another way, if there is an orthonormal basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$, then the eigenvectors of $T^*$ are the same as the eigenvectors of $T$.

Comment: What better answer than from the author himself?